# Opening a new tab in Firefox through the terminal

Tags: command-line, firefox

I want to open a new tab in an existing Firefox instance through bash. [Older answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166223/open-firefox-new-tab-in-same-window-through-terminal) point towards the `-remote` command line option, but this switch has been [depreciated](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1080319) since Firefox 39. The new way to accomplish this is by using the `--new-tab` option:

```
firefox --new-tab
```

However, on Ubuntu this opens a new window instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What's completely undocumented is that Firefox expects a `--url` parameter and will launch a new window otherwise. If you don't want the new tab to navigate to a url, give `about:newtab` as the url parameter.

```
firefox --new-tab --url about:newtab
```

Comment: The correct command is `firefox -new-tab about:newtab`

Comment: This answer is hard to read because you're using incorrect grammar, it's a simple fix just change "an url" to "a url"...

Comment: @TheresaLane i rejected your edit because you changed it to "otherwise it will launch a new window otherwise" which is even more confusing in my opinion. I've repaced the "an" with "a" now

Comment: @TheresaLane i can't fix an edit, only accept or reject it

Comment: I'm getting the following error when trying this:
Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile.

Comment: `firefox -new-tab about:newtab` works, as noted in the comments. Why the `--url` parameter would be required?

Comment: @user598527 - `--url` is useful to open a url in a new tab instead of an empty/home new tab.